# Nested listview causing issue in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I want to have nested listview where there will be vertical listview inside a horizontal listview and that will be wrapped with SingleChildScrollView because I want to scroll all the vertical lists together.

So here's what I have done

```
Expanded(
                    child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                          Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                        ],
                      )),
                    ),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 200.w,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: 5,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: double.infinity,
                                width: 24.w,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                        width: double.infinity,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            0.w, 3.w, 0, 3.w),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        child:
                                        Center(child: Text("Header"))),
                                    ListView.builder(
                                      physics:
                                      const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                      itemCount: 20,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {},
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                0.w, 2.w, 0.w, 2.w),
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "8:44",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 14.sp)),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ))
                  ],
                ))
```

Desired output :

[image]

But in this if I don't put vertical listview in SizedBox and don't give fixed height then it causes an issue.

I want to have expanded or something like wrap_content for vertical inside listview so it takes the required space on it's own.

So what to do for this? Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For vertical  listview you can add physics as NeverScrollable() while for  horizontal one you can add physics except NeverScollable()  and for horizontal list it require height like you have to wrap with container. this will work in your case

Comment: It doesn't work without fix height and shows error : "Infinite height"

Comment: don't wrap  list with infinite container you can wrap list inside flexible and as shrink wrap to true

Comment: @HardikMehta that also doesn't work but can you please tell me any other approach to achieve the table as shown in above image where header is fixed and list is scrollable vertically as well as horizontally.

Comment: what's the error stack trace? The first 2 errors (from the top) should suffice, the whole thing is probably quite lengthy

Comment: @KaranMehta : you want vertial and horizontal scroll both for list with fix header ?

Comment: you can try this : https://sahasuthpala.medium.com/horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-list-view-in-flutter-64be49a98c3f

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
height: double.maxFinite,

in the SizedBox... this will le

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).